# PHP recover data from Post

Tags: php, loops, post

I have inside loop some fields for send inside form with other fields :

```
<?php
for($f=1;$f<=3;$f++)
{
?>
<input type="text" name="friend['email_<?php echo $f;?>']" value="<?php echo $_POST['friend']['email_'.$f.''];?>">
<?php
}
?>
```

When i send from form i need get the value of each field if no empty , i think the problem it´s in  no recover the value send from the form , i don´t know if i writte right

Ony it´s that problem , thank´s , the best regards

Comment: What does `print_r($_POST);` give you?

Comment: Give me nothing , i need show in value in this field the value i put into , when i do submit , regards

Comment: Check your form !!! Make sure you're sending a POST request. Check `var_dump($_REQUEST)` Does it provide you anything? And, Is this code is wriiten on form handler php page?

Comment: Yes all this inside of <form id="tell_form" name="forma" method="post" action="">
</form>

Comment: You should fill the action="" atribute. for ex. action="formprocessing.php"

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is that you have single quotes around `email_<?php echo $f; ?>` - in POST data, these are not needed. So, you would have:

```
<form action="myPage.php" method="POST">
    <?php for ($f=1;$f<=3;$f++) { ?>
        <input type="text" name="friend[email_<?php echo $f; ?>]" value="<?php echo ... ?>">
    <?php } ?>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

PHP will parse POST data into associative arrays, so you will get back a 'friend' object in `$_POST`. You can access this like so:

```
<?php
  $friends = isset($_POST['friend']) ? $_POST['friend'] : array();
  print_r($friends);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if i'm getting it right. You must send your form data in order to manipulate it. For example if you want to print all the form data:

**Client Side:**

```
<form action="boo.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <input type="text" name="age">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

**Server Side:**

```
<?php 

$name = "";
$age = "";

if( isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['age']) )
{
    $name = htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']);
    $age = htmlspecialchars($_POST['age']);
}

echo 'Your name is ' . $name . ' and your age is ' . $age;

?>
```

If you are trying to retain the values even after invalid input you can just `echo` the input in `value` attribute of the `input` field.